# Как в запрос SQL добавить в аргументы метода IN(...) строки из текстового файла?

Tags: sql

Есть текстовый файл который содержит порядка 5 тысяч строк (логины пользователей), необходимо эти логины подставить в аргументы оператора IN, как это проще всего сделать?

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа. Какая СУБД и версия? Откуда выполняется запрос и какими средствами? Где лежит файл и каков его формат?

Answer (score 3):

Мало какие СУБД могут переварить `IN` с таким количеством аргументов.

В данном случае правильнее сделать дополнительную таблицу, загрузить содержимое файла в нее, а затем уже проверять наличие/отсутствия записи в этой таблице.

Comment: MySQL 5.5 переваривает(если изменить дефолтные настройки) до 30к(больше не проверял) параметров в `in (*)`, но с вашим советом полностью солидарен, делать так не стоит.